# Running PHP 5.1 and 5.2 on debian squeeze

Tags: php, debian, php-5.2

I know that Debian Squeeze won't let me compile a PHP version (prior to 5.3.0).

But I need them for migrating some tools: Joomla (1.0.10) and SugarCRM (4.2.1b).

Actually, Joomla 1.0.10 can run on PHP 5.2, and SugarCRM on PHP 5.1.

But both will complain running under PHP 5.3.

So, I want to execute their upgrade process under their working PHP version, so after the upgrade, they may not complain anymore under PHP 5.3.

FYI, Apache is not the only option I have as WebServer.

Maybe I am wrong thinking this way, if so, please explain the differents steps I need.

So the question is: How can I have these PHP versions running on Squeeze?

Answer (score 1):

I did it using CGI, without pinning anything.

I just downloaded the wanted php versions that i needed, compiled them, and use the resulting php-cgi.